# rectangle not showing up in opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Why is rectangle not showing up in my code?

```
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('players.bmp')

#im.shape >>returns (765,1365,3)

cv2.rectangle(im, (64,1248), (191,1311), (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.namedWindow("image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('image', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not show the rectangle, because you are drawing it outside the image.

Why? you may be asking. It is simple. You have this:

```
#im.shape >>returns (765,1365,3)
```

This means

```
rows/height = 765
cols/width = 1365
channels = 3
```

Then you do

```
cv2.rectangle(im, (64,1248), (191,1311), (0,255,0), 2)
```

Here you use 2 points which are tuples (x,y), but you are writing them as if they where tuples (y,x). I know that OpenCV uses in a lot of functions the order (y,x), but this is due that they see the image as a matrix, which commonly is accessed with (row, column) which translates to (y,x). In the case of this rectangle they require **Points** which are expressed in the typical Cartesian way (x,y).

In conclusion, just change it to:

```
cv2.rectangle(im, (1248, 64), (1311, 191), (0,255,0), 2)
```

And it should work.

Comment: thank you bro.. u saved my day... this x and y in cartesian and image coordinates is giving me headache. Is there any simple way to remember

Comment: @NemiBhattarai If it is point, use cartesian, if it is accessing a pixel in an image, use matrix. Use the documentation, if they say point then cartesian. Rects objects are also (x,y,width, height)... I think that is one of the bad parts of OpenCV ....

Answer (score 3):

I had a completely different cause for the issue

for me it wasn't showing up because I was using a numpy view from the image, so instead of using `cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)`, I instead used `frame[..., ::-1]` to convert RGB and BGR.

Somehow this makes the result immutable and when `cv2.rectangle` tries to write to it, it just doesn't get changed.

Comment: Almost 5 years later, and I just wasted about an hour trying to understand why cv2 wont draw a rectangle (and not even throw an error).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question while facing the same problem. In my case, I was correctly passing `x` and `y` along with `x+w` and `y+h`. I had made 2 mistakes though:

- I had this part in a `try` and `except` block (so I couldn't see the exception being raised)
- My code was changing `h` to an array prior to me drawing the rectangle. (I had extracted the values of `x,y,w,h` from `x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)` before mistakenly changing h to `[1,-1,-1,-1]`)